# Arithmetic with ranges

Tags: reference-request

Suppose I have a real number $x$ and a real number $y$. Now it's quite simple to compute their sum $x + y$.

But now, suppose I don't actually know exactly what value $x$ has. But I do know that it's definitely contained in $x_0 \leq x \leq x_1$. Similarly, I know for a fact that $y_0 \leq y \leq y_1$. Now if I'm not mistaken, we have

$$x_0 + y_0 \leq x + y \leq x_1 + y_1$$

I believe this is correct, regardless of sign; adding the two lowest possible values gives me the lowest bound on the correct figure.

What now of multiplication? Well... uh... my first guess would be

$$x_0 \cdot y_0 \leq x \cdot y \leq x_1 \cdot y_1$$

Trouble is, multiplying by a number $k > 1$ makes the product *larger*, whereas multiplying by $k < 1$ makes it *smaller*. So if (for example) we have $x_0 < 1 < x_1$... then I'm not sure what happens! Worse, if we had $x_0 < 0 < x_1$, things appear to get even more complicated.

Things become even more... “interesting” if I wanted, say, the sine of $x$. Now $x_0 < x_1$ does *not* imply that $\sin x_0 < \sin x_1$. OK, so I can easily swap the answers if needed. But, more importantly, $x_0 \leq x \leq x_1$ definitely doesn't imply that $\sin x_0 \leq \sin x \leq \sin x_1$. Even if I swap the two sides of the interval, it's no longer guaranteed to actually contain the true value!

---

Is there a *name* for this system of calculation? (I.e., computing upper and lower limits to the true value rather than just a single approximation to it.) Is there somewhere I can read about a general rule for how to handle it correctly?

Comment: A general rule is that when multiplying an inequality by a negative number, the inequality must be reversed (e.g., $x\ge y\iff -2x\le -2y$), but not when multiplying by a non-negative number (even one less than $1$, e.g., $x\ge y\iff \frac12x\ge\frac12 y$)

Comment: Related to [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic)?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin That looks suspiciously like what I'm looking for!